# Vertical scrollbar although big div is hidden

Tags: css, scrollbar, overflow

I have 2 divs: a login form and a register form.
 - The login form is fairly small
 - The register form is longer than the browser height.

But even when the register div is hidden, I still have that vertical scroll bar...

Is there any way to ONLY disable the scrollbar when a div is active (overflow-y:hidden)

EDIT: My code: http://themavesite.com/testlogin/

Comment: Please post your HTML and CSS.

Comment: how have you hidden your register form div? there is a difference between display:none and visibility:hidden.

Comment: Good point. `visibility: hidden` means it is still given space in the DOM, just not shown.

Comment: @FahadHasan I put my code online: http://themavesite.com/testlogin/

Answer (score 0):

please make sure the vertical bar is showing with the right DIV element,this is probably caused by render scrollbar in outer div

Comment: Not sure what you mean exactly, could you see if I did it correctly here? http://themavesite.com/testlogin/

Answer (score 0):

Please check out [this](http://jsfiddle.net/0ybg2drw/2/) fiddle.

Is it something like this you want? If something has class ".active" then disable body overflow?

HTML:

```
<a class="active">ACTIVE - DISABLE OVERFLOW</a>
<div>"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?""Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</div>
```

CSS:

```
.active{
    color:red;
}
```

JQuery:

```
var act = $(".active");
if (act){
$('html, body').css('overflowY', 'hidden');
}
```

**Note:** As you didn't share your own fiddle, I couldn't edit it, so I made this one.

**Note2:** If the scrollbar you want to hide is from some div instead of body just change the class from  `$(".active")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've added a link to my html and css

Comment: I don't see the problem there. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Well when the login div is active, the scrollbar is there already, even though the register div is hidden (click on registreer to show it)

Comment: That happens because you have the register div `opacity:0;`, instead of `display: none;`.

Comment: If I use display:none; the vertical scrollbar is still there

Comment: I updated the file locally, but I see what's causing this... I also had a margin-bottom in my wrapper.

So now I can fix the vertical scrollbar!
But how do I re-display it the moment I click on the register button?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#register").click(function() { 
    $("#register-form").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#login-form").fadeOut("slow");
  });
});`

Comment: I added that script and updated my files online, however the register form is still hidden when I click it :/
http://themavesite.com/testlogin

Comment: Remove the 'opacity:0'. Try without it and take a look at [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) and [fadein and fadeout](http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-fadein-fadeout-and-fadeto-example/)

Comment: I fixed it by using the following code:             $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".to_register").click(function() {
                    $("#register").fadeIn("slow"); 
                    $("#login").fadeOut("slow");
                    $("#register").css("display","inline"); 
                    $("#login").css("display","none"); 
                    $("#wrapper").css("margin-bottom","900px"); 
                }); 
Same for to_login

Comment: By the way, I recommend you to use `background-repeat:none`. I don't know if you noticed that when you resize the browser, you can see your background repeating.